# Socket.io for realtime and insensitive data and AJAX for sensitive data (username and password)

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm using socket.io for sending things like messages and data that is not sensitive and dangerous in any way.

Now I want to make a login form, I'm worried about sending the username and password for validation using the socket, as I'm worried about privacy and security.

So, what about using AJAX to POST the username and password and return success or not, and leave the public data for socket.io?

I've read about authenticating sockets and securing them but it seems more complex than my model here.

Is there a better model than this one?

Comment: Are you already using SSL on your server ? Without SSL, Ajax or socket.io would be pretty much the same. You could use socket.io for all your communication, which could be easier to maintain, if you enable the use of SSL when connecting.

Comment: so POST doesn't secure the data enough? I'm not using SSL as the website is a very very small one for a very small community, so I don't want to buy an SSL certificate.

Comment: In fact, POST is just a way to send some data to the server. It is not meant for adding security, as it is purely another way of wrapping data sent to the server.

Comment: I strongly advise you to get a certificate in order to enable SSL encryption for both websockets and http methods. I made one for free with https://www.startssl.com, while the procedure is a bit complicated but well explained, the certificate you while obtain is fully recognised by Chrome! (I have not tested other browsers)